# What happens if female cat mate after anti heat injections?

Tags: cats, medicines, breeding

2 days ago I went to the vet for my cat's anti heat injections and he told that it will effect in 36 hours. Then i moved my cat where male cats are also available. If my cat met with the male cat after injection so is there a chance to not get pregnant?